# Lighthouse pwa check fails in bubblewrap even though it passes in chrome

Tags: android, progressive-web-apps, lighthouse, trusted-web-activity, bubblewrap

I was trying to build an apk from pwa using bubblewrap. My pwa is hosted in [Chemistry for CSE](https://rahman24.github.io/chemistryforcse/)
When I initiated bubblewrap with my [manifest](https://rahman24.github.io/chemistryforcse/manifest.json) which was in the root of the above mentioned [webpage](https://rahman24.github.io/chemistryforcse/) using the bubblewrap init

```
bubblewrap init --manifest https://rahman24.github.io/chemistryforcse/manifest.json
```

and after that I build the apk using `bubblewrap build` . While building, this generates a app-release-signed.apk file and after building, when it goes to lighthouse check, score is 88 but the lighthouse pwa check says **no** and there checks failed but the apk files are in the same location.
This is the first problem...**it is not passing the lighthouse pwa check even though it passes this in chrome tools**

and the second problem is, with the apk generated without passing the lighthouse checks, I can install it. But the url bar is showing in the app [like in this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TUHui.png) at the top. But im pwa, it's all fine
Please let me know the things I can do for these two to rectify it
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Lighthouse only shows a **full** pass for PWA if you meet all of their criteria. At the moment you are missing a couple that are required (and probably why you cannot create the apk correctly)

Your PWA for the web appears to work fine but you should do the following:-

### Theme Colour Bar

Add the `<meta name="theme-color" content="#4d084d"/>` to your document `<head>` so it matches your manifest, some older versions of Chrome need both to work which is why it asks you to add it.

### iOS icon

To be correctly installed with a custom icon on iOS you need to add the following to your `<head>` with a link to the relevant icon:
`<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/example.png">`

You should have this anyway as anyone who saves the page to their home screen would otherwise just get a screenshot of the page.

The icon must be either 180px or 192px square to work consistently.

### Android icon

Finally within your manifest you need to add an icon that is maskable:

```
{ 
    "src": "path/to/maskable_icon.png",      
    "sizes": "196x196",     
    "type": "image/png",      
    "purpose": "any maskable"    
}
```

Otherwise on newer Android devices your icon will default to a white background.

My guess is fixing the above will fix your other issues.